# Mac APE installation error >> configure: error: installation or configuration: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: macos, gcc-warning, ape

I am installing APE (Ajax Push Engine) on my MAC. But it is giving me an error during installation,

```
configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C compiler cannot create executables.
```

I have gcc installed on my machine: `gcc -v` gives 'gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)'

How can I remove this error?

Comment: You need to look in the `config.log` file to see why the command failed. There's no way of knowing without seeing the relevant part of that log.

Answer (score 1):

As Mat said, check the `config.log`. I had a similar issue while building SpiderMonkey on ML, and the error turned out to be to do with the configure expecting the C-compiler executables to be called `gcc-4.2` and `g++-4.2` which is not the case in OSX, they are called `gcc` and `g++` instead.

To fix the problem I did:

```
$ export CC=gcc
$ export CXX=g++
$ ./configure
```

This way it worked and succeeded. Thanks to Mat.